# If $[E:F] = p$, with $p$ a prime. There are no intermediate fields between $E$ and $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $E$ be an extension field of the field $F$. If $[E:F]$ is prime, then there are no intermediate fields between $E$ and $F$

Comment: hint: If $K$ is an intermediate field, then what will happen for $[K:F]$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note $[E:F]=[E:K][K:F]$

Comment: help proving ..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider an intermediate field L. From Tower Law we know

$[E:F] = [E:L][L:F]$

Comment: help proving all..